# Proving that open balls and open rectangles form a basis for standard topology of $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

I'm trying to prove that the following sets form bases for the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}^n$:
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{B}_1 & = \{B_r (x) \mid x \in \mathbb{R}^n, r > 0\} & & \text{set of all open balls} \\ 
\mathcal{B}_2 & = \{(a_1, b_1) \times \ldots \times (a_n, b_n) \mid a_i < b_i \in \mathbb{R} \} & & \text{ set of rectangle votes}.
\end{align*}
It makes sense to me, pictorially, that these form bases, but I wanted to prove it more analytically, and I'm not fully convinced that this is the "standard" topology on $\mathbb{R}^n$ or how I would show that. The definition I am working with for a basis is as follows.

> Given a set $X$, a basis $\mathcal{B} \subset \mathcal{P}(X)$ is a collection of subsets of $X$ such that (1) $\bigcup\limits_{B \in \mathcal{B}} B = X$ and (2) if $B_1, B_2 \in \mathcal{B}$ and $x \in B_1 \cap B_2$, then there exists $B \in \mathcal{B}$ such that $x \in B \subset B_1 \cap B_2$.

Here is my attempt, beginning with $\mathcal{B}_1$.

> First we show that $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a union of open balls. For each $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, consider $B_{1} (x)$, the open ball of radius $1$ centered at $x$. I claim that
> $$ 
> \bigcup\limits_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} B_1 (x) = \mathbb{R}^n.
> $$
> As $B_r (x) \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ by definition, we have $\bigcup\limits_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} B_1 (x) \subset \mathbb{R}^n$. Furthermore, given $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, we have $x \in B_1 (x) \subset \bigcup\limits_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} B_1 (x)$. Furthermore, as we've only used a subset of all open balls, we have
> $$ 
> \bigcup\limits_{r > 0; x \in \mathbb{R}^n} B_r (x) \supset \bigcup\limits_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} B_1 (x) = \mathbb{R}^n.
> $$
> where $\supset$ is an equality since $B_r (x) \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ for each $r$ and $x$.
>
> Let $B_1, B_2 \in \mathcal{B}$, so for $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\epsilon, \delta > 0$, we have $B_1 = B_{\epsilon} (x)$ and $B_2 = B_{\delta} (y)$. Suppose that $p \in B_1 \cap B_2 = B_{\epsilon} (x) \cap B_{\delta} (y)$. Now set
> $$ 
> r = \min\left(\epsilon - d(x,p), \delta - d(y,p)\right). 
> $$
> I claim that $B_r (p) \subset B_1 \cap B_2$. Let $q \in B_r (p)$, we have
> $$ 
> d(x,q) \leq d(x,p) + d(p,q) < d(x,p) + r \leq d(x,p) + (\epsilon - d(x,p)) = \epsilon
> $$
> so $q \in B_{\epsilon} (x)$. Similarly, we have
> $$ 
> d(y,q) \leq d(y,p) + d(p,q) < d(y,p) + r \leq d(y,p) + (\delta - (y,p)) < \delta, 
> $$
> so $q \in B_{\delta} (y)$, so $q \in B_{\delta} (x) \cap B_{\epsilon} (y)$, so $B_r (p) \subset B_{\delta} (x) \cap B_{\epsilon} (y)$. By definition, $B_r (p) \in \mathcal{B}_1$, so the second condition is satisfied.

Though I believe I've demonstrated that $\mathcal{B}_1$ is a basis for some topology on $\mathbb{R}^n$, I don't know how one would show this is the "standard" topology. I assume that this follows from the definition. To define an open ball, I need to define a metric. It's assumed that I'm using the Euclidean metric. Every open set is a union of open balls, so that gives me precisely the same topology. Is that correct?

Moving to $\mathcal{B}_2$, which I'm less certain about. I think the reason this would generate the "standard" topology is because the set of open rectangles are "open balls" in the square metric, which one can prove induces the same topology on $\mathbb{R}^n$ as the Euclidean metric. Is that the correct idea, or is there more to it?

> I assume the proof that the union of the basis elements is all of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is exactly analogous. For each $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, I form an "open ball" (open rectangle) in the square metric and verify that unioning over all of those open balls gives all of $\mathbb{R}^n$. The proof I gave above doesn't depend on any specific metric, so I think the same proof carries over.
>
> To prove the second condition: Let $B_1, B_2$ in $\mathcal{B}_2$, so
> \begin{align*} 
> B_1 & = (a_1, b_1) \times \ldots \times (a_n, b_n) \\ 
> B_2 & = (c_1, d_1) \times \ldots \times (c_n, d_n),
> \end{align*}
> where for each $i$, we have $a_i < b_i$ and $c_i < d_i$. I believe I can just take
> $$ 
> B_3 = (a_1, b_1) \cap (c_1, d_1) \times \ldots \times (a_n, b_n) \cap (c_n, d_n). 
> $$
> This makes sense to me in the case $n = 2$, but I'm not fully certain that it generalizes to the case of $n$ dimensions.

> If $x \in B_1 \cap B_2$, then for each $i$, $x_i \in (a_i, b_i)$ and $x_i \in (c_i, d_i)$ so $x_i \in (a_i, b_i) \cap (c_i, d_i)$, so I think I can just take $B_3 = B_1 \cap B_2$.

My main questions, aside from feedback on the above, is:

1. Is my understanding of why these induce the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}^n$ correct? If not, how could I prove that?
2. I'm not certain I've proved the second condition for a basis for $\mathcal{B}_2$, so I'd appreciate some feedback on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us consider $\mathcal B_1$ and let $\tau_1$ be the topology of which $\mathcal B_1$ is a basis. Let $\tau$ be standard topology. The idea is to prove that $\tau_1=\tau$. Since each element of $\mathcal B_1$ belongs to $\tau$, and since each element of $\tau_1$ is an union of elements of $\mathcal B_1$, $\tau_1\subset\tau$. On the other hand, if $A\in\tau$, then, for each $a\in A$, there is an open ball $B_{r_a}(a)$ such that $B_{r_a}(a)\subset A$. Each $B_{r_a}(a)$ belongs to $\mathcal B_1$, and therefore $A\left(=\bigcup_{a\in A}B_{r_a}(a)\right)\in\tau_1$.

A similar argument proves that $\tau=\tau_2$.

What you did concerning $\mathcal B_2$ looks fine.

Comment: The only thing I'm confused on is: how do I know that every element of $\mathcal{B}_1$ belongs to $\tau$?

Comment: How do you define the standard topology on $\Bbb R^n$?

Comment: The best characterization I have is "the topology induced by the Euclidean metric," but that may not be the best.

Comment: Fine. The elements of $\mathcal B_1$ are the sets $B_r(x)$, which are open balls with respect to the Euclidean metric. Therefore, they are open sets with respect to the topology induced by that metric.